# Page is getting reloaded automatically on ng-click - Only on hosting server

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have SPA. In which I have anchor tags which are to set to differnt urls using ng-href.

If I click on any of the links,the page is NOT reloaded and ng-template is rendered, No such issue on deploying to site on local server.

But on moving deployed site to hosting server a strange issue, I am facing.

Suppose you have below links

```
<a ng-href='/albums'> Albums </a>
<a ng-href='/music'> Music </a>
```

Now suppose users clicks on Albums, it will not refresh the page immediately but after few seconds the page is auto reloaded however, meanwhile template is rendered as well.

I mean to say if you click on Albums links, template is rendered and then the page is reloaded.

> One more thing when I inspect console some irrelavant messges in console like min 1 ad needed, mute game hosted, no clue about it and  it is poiting to some unknown file named program which if I try to open, it opens chrome tools screen

FYI. I am using ASP.Net 4.5 MVC

Comment: can you share a url for us?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you put a hash tag before an Angular route to let the Browser's engine know that it's not a regular href.
`<a ng-href='#albums'> Albums </a>`
`<a ng-href='#music'> Music </a>`

See [Routing with Angular JS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)

Comment: jmb.mage..no its not necessary